# Change Xcode Unicode Font?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unicode, fonts

I'm trying to create a keyboard for iOS that outputs a specific unicode. However, the unicode provided in iOS uses a subpar font that I want to change. Is it possible to assign a new font to the unicode and have it output in messenger?

Comment: Unclear. What does "outputs a specific unicode" mean? Or "assign a new font to the unicode"? Or "messenger", for that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not use custom fonts((( https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html

Comment: i realize i can’t use a custom font. apple has a unicode already for the language i want but they are usinga horrible font. actually the unicode page shows numerous fonts for the each letter but it will only print the bad font.

Comment: @MinaMakar this is called font. And again, you cannot change it